# Can CSS or jQuery override injected onkeyup attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am using a Chrome extension to modify an `input` element by adding a function that triggers an alert if the text exceeds 30 characters:

```
inputElement.onkeyup = function () { ... some code here ... };
```

Before a UI update to the app this worked as expected. Now it's broken. The new UI has changed superficially, reflecting, I presume, new CSS. I can alter `inputElement`'s default value so I know I'm still hitting the element correctly. Could new CSS or possibly the app's own jQuery be preventing my function from working? If so, is there a solution?

**Update:** Just to clarify. My question isn't, "Why isn't the code below not working? It's, "Can injecting an `onkeyup` into an input form that does not currently have this attribute be broken by some other feature of a web app, such as CSS or jQuery?" I have as, Maximillian Laumeister suggests, tried the `addEventListener` method, and this works. Though, is this foolproof? Is there a foolproof solution at all? Or is it more of test with each update to the app and reevaluate?

Comment: In response to your edit, I do believe that `addEventListener` is pretty much "foolproof", as long as the original app doesn't do anything weird or hacky with their code, because `addEventListener` doesn't modify any event listeners that are already there. Please see my edited answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

To inject an `onkeyup` function without affecting any `onkeyup` function that is already there, you should use an event listener.

If there is an existing `onkeyup` function or event listener, buy using `addEventListener` we are just adding to what's there, so it will not interfere with existing functionality.

If there is no existing `onkeyup` function it works too - again because by using `addEventListener` we are not touching any function assignment or event listener that may or may not already be there.

---

Here is how you can add your event listener in code (live demo):

```js
document.getElementById("theinput").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (this.value.length > 30) alert("Greater than 30 chars");
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = this.value.length;
});
```

```html
<div>Type in the box to see character count</div>
<input id="theinput" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, messed up the syntax a little and forgot `this`. I guess my point is is using `anElement.onkeyup = function () ...` the correct way to inject onkeyup functionally, or can something in the app's own coded prevent this from working (what I assume is going on)? If so, is there a foolproof alternative?

Comment: @Peter If the app also binds a function to `onkeyup`, then there could be a conflict. To fix this, you can use an event listener instead of binding `onkeyup` directly. Please see my edited post above.